# Running PHP application inside the destructor

Tags: php, oop, destructor

Let's say I have a typical PHP app, which is basically a router, like Sinatra in Rails:

```
$app = new App($some_config);
$app->get('/', function($app){
  display_homepage();
});
```

That code does nothing else but register that function on the "/" route.

Is it a good idea to match the routes against the request URI and run the registered functions inside the `__destruct()` magic method? That way I don't need to call a special function, like `$app->run()`. I assume nothing is actually "destroyed" until __destruct ends, right?

The reason I'm asking is to see if I have a chance winning the Nobel prize. Notice how all PHP routers require you to call some kind of run() method after you define the routes? Mine would be the first that does that automatically!

Comment: That is a thing you can do. It's not a sane thing, nor is it what destructors are intended for, and anyone looking at your code will wonder what you were smoking when you wrote it, but it is a thing that you can do.

Comment: My first instinct is to ask why you picked the destructor, rather than the constructor, to do all your magic. Then I got to wondering what other magic methods you could abuse this way; perhaps `__toString()` and then `echo` the object to run it? Or perhaps you could use `__set` and write `$my_object->do_magic = true;`

Comment: It is not possible in the constructor because I have to allow new routes to be registered. The echo with __toString sounds interesting

Comment: @thelolcat You do realise I was joking, right? The only prize you'll win for this would be for obfuscated code. And there's a lot of competition for that.

Comment: On a practical note, [destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.destruct) execute in a particular context (e.g. no exceptions allowed), particularly if you are relying on reaching the end of the script and them executing during PHP's shutdown phase (at which point *lots* of things become impossible).

Answer (score 0):

There is some reason not to do so.

You cannot "catch" fatal errors with `register_shutdown_function` because it works before destructors: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/main.c#L1769

You cannot catch exception of this destructor from outside, even with `set_exception_handler`.

So, your visitor could see white screen(or, even worse, errors).